# Reference to type 'CancellationToken' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime'

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to generate some class by using Roslyn api however I can't compile generated code successfully becouse of that error. It sounds:

```
error CS7069: Reference to type 'CancellationToken' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
```

what I'm trying to do is:

```
var objLocation = typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location;
var path = new FileInfo(objLocation);
var directory = path.Directory;
Compilation = Compilation.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(objLocation));
        Compilation = Compilation.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "System.dll")));
        Compilation = Compilation.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "System.Runtime.dll")));
```

As far as I see, the `System.Runtime.dll` is only placeholder that references different libraries so I don't understand why the message appear and why the compiler is looking for that type here.

Could some point me something?

Comment: `CancellationToken` is part of mscorlib

Comment: @CoryNelson mscorlib is referenced via System.Runtime

Comment: @Puchacz no, you need to reference mscorlib specifically. I think this may have to do with the types being forwarded rather than a “hard” assembly reference, but that is just my guess.

Comment: @CoryNelson you mean instead of System.Runtime or with it? When I'm trying to do instead, then I am getting `the type Object is defined in assembly that is not referenced`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are compiling for .net core.

CancellationToken resides in mscorlib.dll, so you need to reference that as well.

Comment: I'm compiling for .NET Standard and tried include mscorlib also without sucess. Same error.

Comment: Ah. In net standard pre 2.0 this was defined in System.Threading.Tasks.

Comment: See here: https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Threading.CancellationToken

Comment: I'm using netstandard 2.0. I started to try reference also `C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.NETCore.App\\2.0.0\\netstandard.dll` however it seems not to be working.